# Understanding asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm new to asynchronous programming, and I'm having a hard time getting the concept.
Please help!!!

Ive come up with a simple example:

> for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
>     setTimeout(function () {
>       console.log(i);
>     }, 1000);
>   }

All I want is to print the indexes in ascending order but due to asynchronous action forced by the setTimeout i'm getting the last index printed out 10 times.

I understand why this happens...

No matter what I've tried (I don't think my misunderstanding needs elaboration) I failed solving this stupid riddle...

Im obviously missing something basic.
Please help me figure it out.

Comment: I think it's the concept of closures that's confusing you, not asynchronous calls. What you're doing there is setting 10 timeouts, each of which will wait for a second before firing. When they do fire, they will each refer back to 'i', which now equals 10.

Comment: Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function(a,b){ setTimeout(console.log.bind(console,b), b * 1000);})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because all those functions use the same variable `i`, which is equal to `10` during invocation of them. Try something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
 setTimeout((function (k) {
  return function(){
    console.log(k);
  }
 }(i)), 1000);
}
```

It's because JavaScript has closures. You can read about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: cant vote you up (im new) but thanks anyways :)

Comment: Ive read about closures for the last few hours, I still cant figure out what you did to solve the problem. Could you try explaining me please?